# How do I include rows from dataframe that contain certain keywords

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, reddit

I'm analysing reddit threads for an assignment and I only want to include threads that contain certain keywords.

I have a list of keywords: `keywords <- c(addict', 'addicted', 'addiction','addictive', 'afraid' ,'anxiety','anxious','cry','crying','delusion','delusional')`

The dataframe has 3 columns. I want to only include rows that contain one of the keywords in the column called title.

e.g.

|  | title | created_utc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anyone have a RH wallet yet? Asking for a friend | 164128421 |
| 2 | Ravi Menon, managing director of the Monetary Auth... | 164131283 |
| 3 | Different Augmented Reality(AR) NFT apps and marke... | 164134123 |

`keywordstest2<-paste0(keywords, collapse = "|")`
`dfsub%>% filter(grepl(keywordstest2,title))`

Tried this, obvs didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this. Thanks :D

Comment: Sorry, just accepted it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I extended the example to contain 2 of the keywords

EDIT, as mentioned by Merijn in the comments adding word boundaries `\\b` to exclude false positives since `grepl` does partial matching

```
library(dplyr)

keywords <- c("addict", "addicted", "addiction", "addictive", "afraid", "anxiety",
"anxious", "cry", "crying", "delusion", "delusional")

df %>% filter(grepl(paste0("\\b",paste(keywords, 
  collapse="\\b|\\b"),"\\b"), df$title))
  id                                                             title
1  1         Anyone have a RH wallet yet? Asking delusion for a friend
2  3 Different Augmented Reality(AR) NFT apps and anxiety and marke...
  created_utc
1   164128421
2   164134123
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, title = c("Anyone have a RH wallet yet? Asking delusion for a friend",
"Ravi Menon managing director of the Monetary Auth... crypto", "Different Augmented Reality(AR) NFT apps and anxiety and marke..."
), created_utc = c(164128421L, 164131283L, 164134123L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Comment: @BenJohnson Hm, it skipped the 2nd row in the example, so should work in general. Did you check the names like `df`,`title`, `keywords` etc? Maybe a typo?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi, sorry just 1 more question. If I wanted to export my filtered dataset as a csv what's the best way to go about this.

Comment: @BenJohnson Use write.csv() for that (type ?write.csv for more help).

Comment: that would match crypto (if present) based on cry too

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfsub %>% 
filter(grepl('addict|addicted|addiction|addictive|afraid|anxiety|anxious|cry|crying|delusion|delusional', title))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `tidyverse` option. I collapse your keywords into a searchable list (e.g., addict or addicted or ...). Then, I use `str_detect` on `title` to look for any of those keywords and if so, then those rows are kept (using `filter`).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(title, paste(keywords, collapse = "|")))
```

Or base R, you can filter in one line:

```
df[grep(paste(keywords, collapse = "|"),df$title),]
```

**Output**

```
  id                                                             title created_utc
1  1         Anyone have a RH wallet yet? Asking delusion for a friend   164128421
2  3 Different Augmented Reality(AR) NFT apps and anxiety and marke...   164134123
```

**Data**

```
df <-
 structure(
   list(
     id = 1:3,
     title = c(
       "Anyone have a RH wallet yet? Asking delusion for a friend",
       "Ravi Menon managing director of the Monetary Auth...",
       "Different Augmented Reality(AR) NFT apps and anxiety and marke..."
     ),
     created_utc = c(164128421L, 164131283L, 164134123L)
   ),
   class = "data.frame",
   row.names = c(NA,-3L)
 )

keywords <- c('addict', 'addicted', 'addiction','addictive', 'afraid' ,'anxiety','anxious','cry','crying','delusion','delusional')
```

For filtering on 2 columns, then you could do something like this:

```
df %>%
  filter(Reduce(`|`, across(
    c(title, selftext), .fns = ~ str_detect(., paste(keywords, collapse = "|"))
  )))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this relative small keyword list concatenation the `|` is an option, but you run into issues when that string to match becomes too large. Also this far the answers given also matches "crypto" based on a keyword "cry". I adapted the `df` a bit to include the word "crypto".

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, title = c("Anyone have a RH wallet yet? Asking delusion for a friend",
"Ravi Menon managing director of the Monetary crypto Auth...", "Different Augmented Reality(AR) NFT apps and anxiety and marke..."
), created_utc = c(164128421L, 164131283L, 164134123L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

keywords <- c("addict", "addicted", "addiction", "addictive", "afraid", "anxiety",
"anxious", "cry", "crying", "delusion", "delusional")

library(stringr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(any(stri_trans_tolower(stri_extract_all_words(title)[[1]]) %in% keywords))

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   id [2]
#      id title                                                             created_utc
#   <int> <chr>                                                                   <int>
# 1     1 Anyone have a RH wallet yet? Asking delusion for a friend           164128421
# 2     3 Different Augmented Reality(AR) NFT apps and anxiety and marke...   164134123
```